# How to include variable to output filename using awk

Tags: shell, awk

There is a command which prints out to file range of values from CSV file:

```
date1var=mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
date2var=mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
awk -F, -v d1var="$date1var" -v d2var="$date2var" '$1 > d1var && $1 <= d2var {print $0 }' OFS=, plot_data.csv > graph1.csv
```

I'm just guessing if it's possible to include my variables to the output filename?

Final name of the file should be similar to:

```
graph_d1var-d2var.csv
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output of `print` command to a file name, like:

```
awk -F, -v d1var="$date1_var" -v d2var="$date2var" '
    $1 > d1var && $1 <= d2var {
        print > ("graph_" d1var "-" d2var ".csv") 
    }' 
OFS=, plot_data.csv
```

This uses the values of `d1var` and `d2var` to create the name of the output file. If you want the name of the variables, surround the whole name in double quotes.

Comment: `print $0 > "graph_" d1var "-" d2var ".csv"` is ambiguous, some awks will parse it as `(print $0> "graph_") d1var "-" d2var ".csv"`. You always need to parenthesize string concatenation on the right side of a redirection symbol: `print > ("graph_" d1var "-" d2var ".csv")`. I dropped the unnecessary `$0` too.

Comment: thanks Birei & @EdMorton, I did not know the concatenation trick, very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Let the shell handle it: you're starting with shell variables after all

```
date1var=mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
date2var=mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v d1var="$date1var" \
                 -v d2var="$date2var" \
'
# awk script is unchanged
' plot_data.csv > "graph1_${date1var}-${date2var}.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
date1var="1234"
date2var="5678"
awk -F, -v d1="$date1var" -v d2="$date2var" '{print > ("graph" d1 "-" d2 ".txt")}' OFS=, plot_data.csv
```

Note that you can't compare date strings in awk like you are trying to do. You also have a typo, in that you have written `date1_var` with an underscore whereas you have used `date1var` without an underscore further on.

I guess the short answer is that you can print to a named file with `print > "filename"` and that you can concatenate (join) strings by placing them beside each other like this `string2 = string1 "and" string3;`

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I fixed typo. Could you please also explain why can't I compare date strings this way? It looks like it's working. I know that the date format I'm using is terrible but that the incoming CSV file format...

Comment: `print $0> "graph" d1 "-" d2 ".txt"` is ambiguous, some awks will parse it as `(print $0> "graph") d1 "-" d2 ".txt"`. You always need to parenthesize string concatenation on the right side of a redirection symbol: `print > ("graph" d1 "-" d2 ".txt")`. I dropped the unnecessary `$0` too.